# how to find limit of several variables using y=mx?

Tags: limits

How to evaluate
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{ax^2+by^2}{cy^2+dx^2} $$
using $y=mx$?

Here what I've done:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ax^2 + b(mx)^2}{c(mx)^2 + dx^2}&= \frac{x^2(ax+bm^2)}{x^2(cm^2 + d)}\\
&= \frac{ax + bm^2}{cm^2 +d}
\end{align*}

Comment: Are the constants positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right  idea but I think some mistakes slipped it:

$$\frac{ax^2+b(mx)^2}{c(mx)^2+dx^2}=\frac{x^2(a+bm^2)}{x^2(cm^2+d)}=\frac{a+bm^2}{cm^2+d}$$

and thus the limit doesn't exist as it depends on the parameter $\;n\;$ .

Comment: Isn't $\frac{a+bm^2}{cm^2+d}$ the value of the limit? It shouldn't matter that $m$ is a variable, because the limit is taken with respect to $x$.

Comment: @architectpianist Nop. The limit **must be** independent of the way $\;(x,y)\;$ approach $\;(0,0)\;$ in order to exist. In this case, it is shown it completely depends on the slope of the line $\;y=mx\;$ to approach the origin.

Comment: Oh, so we're using $y=mx$ to show the direction of approaching (0,0), not as an actual function of $x$. Thanks for helping me understand!